# How to disable form button on ajax callback?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a button with ajax callback and I want to disable it on button click without page reload. Preferably inside `ajax_function` but it's not obligatory.

```
$form['my_button'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::ajax_function',
    'wrapper' => 'my-button-wrapper',
  ],
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('glyphicon', 'glyphicon-shopping-cart'),
  ),
  '#submit' => ['::ajaxButtonSubmit'],
];
```

Comment: I did this with a Javascript behavior in Drupal 7 disabling an overlay and also adding an overlay on the page to prevent clicks. It did not have a non-JavaScript fallback.

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax callback function write the code to disable button. like:

```
public function ajax_function(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['my_button']['#attributes']['disabled'] = true;
    return $form['my_button'];
}
```

Hope it helps!